# React Radiobuttons only triggering onChange when unchecked

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, radio-button

I'm currenty having some issues with radio buttons in React.js. For some reason the button that was just unselected triggers the onChange event, while the button that was selected does nothing. I'm currently only able to get the value of the previously selected radio button.

I'm handeling the change event inside my App.js and passing it down to RadioButtons.jsx as a prop

Inside App.js:

```js
constructor(){
    super();
    
    this.state = {
        selectedOption: "medium_term"
    }
  }
  
  handleOptionChange = changeEvent => {
       
        this.setState({
            selectedOption: changeEvent.target.value

        });
        this.getTop10();
        
        console.log(this.state.selectedOption); //shows previous button
    };
    
    render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">          
          <RadioButtons onChange={this.handleOptionChange} selectedOption={this.state.selectedOption}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Example: one of my radio buttons

```html
<div className="radio row mx-1 my-0">
  <label>
      <input
          type="radio"
          name="timeframe"
          value="medium_term"
          onChange={this.props.onChange}
          checked={this.props.selectedOption === "medium_term"}
          className="form-check-input"
      />
      the last 6 months
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't forget that Set state is async. Also this CodePen is a simple example showing how to implement Radio buttons in React: https://codepen.io/magnusb/pen/yzmXab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous so if you try to console log the state, it will return the previous state instead.

If you want to `console.log` the newly set state instantly after setting the state, you need to do it in the `setState()` callback like this:

```
this.setState({
    selectedOption: changeEvent.target.value
}, function() {console.log(this.state.selectedOption); });

this.getTop10();
```